# Return Null loses Parameters in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, pagereference

I have a Savepoint set in apex controller. Inside the try block, I am having Pagereference set to redirect to newly created record id page.

On Catch block, I simply want to put return null so that any validation rule error will come in my page as page message.

**Code Snippet**

```
try{
.............
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + c.Id + '/e') ;
                pageRef.setRedirect(true) ;
                return pageRef ;

       }
      catch (Exception ex) {
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            return null; 
        }
```

For a situation when exception is caught, the page simply get it's parameters lost.

Can someone let me know, how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parameters are not lost, as they're still in the view state. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Page messages not showing and the whole page becomes blank

Comment: There's something else wrong with your code. Simply returning null should not have any adverse effect on the page.

Comment: `return null; ` will refresh whole page

Comment: I don't want to refresh the whole page. Just want to show the validation rules that are thrown

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Can you please suggest a way out?

Comment: Rather then automatically redirecting, you can change the method to `void` and display a success message. If you make sure your button or link has a `rerender` attribute it wont do a page refresh, and you can create a `view record` button or link that can redirect the user instead. Chances are there is a bigger issue in your code, but this may be a way to workaround the issue (not posting as answer as I don't necessarily recommend this approach).

Comment: I can't make it a void method as I need to navigate to a new page on successful operations. For Validation issues I need to stick to previous page